# error: postfix ‘unaryOperators unaryOperators::operator++(const unaryOperators&)’ must take ‘int’ as its argument

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

`unaryOperators operator++ (const unaryOperators &one);`
For this declared inside the class, I should get the error *"too many arguments"* etc. but the error I get is:

`error: postfix ‘unaryOperators unaryOperators::operator++(const unaryOperators&)’ must take ‘int’ as its argument`

Why ***must take ‘int’ as its argument***? What does it mean?

GCC Linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html#faq-13.14):

> Since the prefix and postfix ++ operators can have two definitions, the C++ language gives us two different signatures. Both are called operator++(), but the prefix version takes no parameters and the postfix version takes a dummy int.

Answer (score 6):

There are 2 different operators for increment, postfix and prefix.

The overload of postfix takes a dummy int parameter to distinguish it.

```
T& operator ++(T& a);     //prefix
T operator ++(T& a, int); // postfix
```

Comment: I don't know how Bjarne sleeps at night, with this feature in his language.

Answer (score 3):

There are two `++` operators. One takes zero parameters (prefix), and the other takes a single int parameter (postfix). The compiler thinks that you want the second one (note the word 'postfix' in the error message), and it's telling you that the parameter type is wrong. From your confusion, it appears that the compiler's attempt to be helpful was misguided and you actually wanted the first one.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to overload the prefix operator (`++x`), this can be done as either:

- A non-static member function with no parameters, `operator++()`; or
- A non-member function with one parameter, `operator++(const unaryOperators &)`.

If you declare it as a member function with a parameter, it's interpreted as a declaration of the postfix operator (`x++`); however, a postfix operator must be declared with a dummy argument of type `int`, not your type, hence the error.

So, either remove the function argument, and have the operator act on `this`; or move the function outside the class; or make it a `friend` if it needs access to the type's privates.